# Configure mailgun in TypeScript for Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions, mailgun

I'm doing a Cloud Function in Firebase to send an email with mailgun following the [documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#sending-via-api).

I'm using **TypeScript** and I can not find an example about how to set up the API KEY, DOMAIN and how to send the email at the end. All the examples I have found are in JavaScript.

Example in **JavaScript**:

```
var API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
var DOMAIN = 'YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME';
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: API_KEY, domain: DOMAIN});

const data = {
  from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
  to: 'foo@example.com, bar@example.com',
  subject: 'Hello',
  text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!'
};

mailgun.messages().send(data, (error, body) => {
  console.log(body);
});
```

**TypeScript**:

```
const API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
const DOMAIN = 'YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME';

import * as mailgun from 'mailgun-js';
// How to set up ?

// How to send the email ?
```

I have tried using [ts-mailgun](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mailgun), a wrapper for sending emails, but, didn't work because of an error while deploying the function.

My goal is to configure mailgun correctly using TypeScript to send an email to a user.

Comment: What error did you receive, and have you upgraded your plan to Flame or Blaze... you'll need one of these paid plans to make API requests to non-Google services?

Answer (score 2):

`npm i ts-mailgun`

then:

```js
import { NodeMailgun } from 'ts-mailgun';

const mailer = new NodeMailgun();
mailer.apiKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; // Set your API key
mailer.domain = 'mail.my-sample-app.com'; // Set the domain you registered earlier
mailer.fromEmail = 'noreply@my-sample-app.com'; // Set your from email
mailer.fromTitle = 'My Sample App'; // Set the name you would like to send from

mailer.init();

// Send an email to test@example.com
mailer
    .send('test@example.com', 'Hello!', '<h1>hsdf</h1>')
    .then((result) => console.log('Done', result))
    .catch((error) => console.error('Error: ', error));
```

from the [ts-mailgun documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mailgun)

Comment: How can `host` be change with ts-mailgun?

Comment: ts-mailgun simply does not work with yarn https://github.com/StatelessStudio/ts-mailgun/issues/36#issuecomment-628891201

Comment: @AngelS.Moreno That issue has been resolved and it's working with yarn for some time

Answer (score 2):

This question is from over a year ago, but after inspecting the linked GitHub page in the `@types/mailgun-js` page here:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/58081d555e64d07049d2da6115e5118240162c73/types/mailgun-js/index.d.ts#L18

You can see the ConstructorParams interface, and see where it is called. It looks like you need to instantiate `mailgun` like below. After doing this, the types started working for me.

```
import mg from 'mailgun-js';

const api_key = process.env.MG_API_KEY as string;
const DOMAIN = process.env.MG_DOMAIN as string;
const mailgun = new mg({apiKey: api_key, domain: DOMAIN});
const UsersMailList = mailgun.lists(process.env.USERS_LIST as string);
```